# Show a success message for a short period (without a race condition) in Rxjs

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

A button gets clicked, performs an action, and a success message gets shown briefly, based on the boolean values in the stream.

```
let copied: Observable<boolean> = fromEvent(button, "click").pipe(
  mergeMap(() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(...)), // writeText returns a promise
  switchMap(() => [of(true), of(false).pipe(delay(1000))]),
  startWith(false),
);
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as I've got Observables in switchMap, not values.

We need `false -> Click -> perform action -> true -> delay -> false`

Note, if the button is quickly clicked again, the message shouldn't disappear (hoping to solve the obvious race condition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close.  Instead of returning an array inside your `switchMap`, return an observable that emits the two values you want.  You can use `concat` to create a single observable from your two sources `of(true)` and `of(false).pipe(delay(1000))`:

```js
const copied: Observable<boolean> = fromEvent(button, 'click').pipe(
  mergeMap(() => navigator.clipboard.writeText('')),
  switchMap(() => concat(of(true), of(false).pipe(delay(1000)))),
  startWith(false),
);
```